# How do I update my columns value in my 2 dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

Building a Sudoku game. How can I update my 2 dimensional array with the users input if they decide to input data using columns and not rows? I can not figure out why it will not work properly?

```
    else if (dataSelection == 2) {
        if (boardSize == 1) {
            int column = 1; 
            int column2 = 0; 
            while (column < 4) {
                Scanner firstColumn4x4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter four values using commas for column " + column);
                String column1Values4x4 = firstColumn4x4.next();
                String strArray[] = column1Values4x4.split(",");
                int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                    arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                }
                ***fourArray[column-1][column2] = arraySidesInteger[column2];*** //can not figure out thisstatement 
                for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fourArray.length; j++)
                        System.out.print(fourArray[i][j] + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                }
                column++;
                column2++;                  
            }
```

If user inputs 1,2,3,4 for column 1, I want it to print out:
1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0
4 0 0 0

However I keep getting:
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure arraySidesInteger is actually parsing the input correctly? Also, why does `column` appear to be 1-based and `column2` appear to be 0-based? Shouldn't one of those probably be named to `row`?

Comment: @crand6 Yeah you are right. It was not parsing correctly. I need to clean up my code as well. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never looping over the rows to actually insert the user's values. For the line

```
fourArray[column-1][column2] = arraySidesInteger[column2];
```

you probably want something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySidesInteger.length(); i++) {
    fourArray[i][column2] = arraySidesInteger[i];
}
```

and just do away with the `column` variable altogether.

(EDIT: Accordingly, since `column2` is the variable that you are actually using to index to the right column, the while loop should be looping on that, not `column`.)